# declaring a variable across multiple source files

Tags: c

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

I have the following in my service.h file

```
enum service_state_code {
    NO_ERROR_OK,
    ERROR_INCORRECT_STATE,
    ERROR_EMPTY_STRING,
    ERROR_NO_COMMAND_FOUND
};

const char *service_state_msg[] = {
    "OK:",
    "ERROR: Incorrect state for modifying service channel state",
    "ERROR: No command found",
    "ERROR: No command parameters",
    NULL
};

get_channel_service_state(channel_t *channel, const char *msg);
```

And I have 2 other *.c files that will include the service.h file.

`network.c` and `socket.c`

And I use it something like this:

```
get_channel_service_state(channel, ss7_service_state_msg[ERROR_INCORRECT_STATE]);
```

However, I get a linker error complaining about the:

```
multiple definition of service_state_msg first defined here
```

I know the reason why I am getting this error. As the `service_state_msg` is being defined twice as a global in service.h for each time it is included in a *.c file.

I am just asking what is the best way to being about to use `service_state_msg` across multiple *.c source files?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make `service_state_msg` `extern` in the header file:

```
extern const char *service_state_msg[];
```

And then move this:

```
const char *service_state_msg[] = {
    "OK:",
    "ERROR: Incorrect state for modifying service channel state",
    "ERROR: No command found",
    "ERROR: No command parameters",
    NULL
};
```

to any one of your C files. Alternatively, you could leave the initialization in the header file but make `service_state_msg` static:

```
static const char *service_state_msg[] = {
    "OK:",
    "ERROR: Incorrect state for modifying service channel state",
    "ERROR: No command found",
    "ERROR: No command parameters",
    NULL
};
```

But be aware that this means every object file will have a copy of the `service_state_msg` array, and will all need to be recompiled if it changes.

Comment: Thanks, I used the first example with extern. However, I don't really like to duplicate code as you will have to change all the source files. Using the static method is just another global.

Answer (score 1):

Define and initialize in a .C file. Use following in the header file.

```
extern char ** service_state_msg; // in the header file
```